# android how to design this layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've got an example layout that I'm trying to create in android using xml. I am able to create similar layouts but I feel as if my approach might be wrong.

What I have been doing in these cases is nesting relative layouts to act as a "row". The below image demonstrates what I would do.

[image: layout]

How would you guys create a layout similar to this? I feel as if nesting relative layouts is overkill but I'm not sure how I can keep everything centred if I don't.

When I didn't nest the layouts I used

```
android:layout_toRightOf="..."
android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
```

on t5, t6 and t7 (from the image). The result looked incorrect. t1, t2, t3 and t4 wasn't centred horizontally any more.

Is there a way to like tell the relative layout that everything after this point should appear on a new row? Or is relative layouts the wrong way to go for things like this? I don't think a table layout would work correctly since each row doesn't necessarily need to have the same amount of views and they need to be centred.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure why someone down voted my question. A comment letting me know why and I would gladly fix the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could nest two horizontal `LinearLayouts` within a vertical `LinearLayout`.  Maybe not so efficient as a `RelativeLayout`, but easier to get the centering behavior you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="D" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="F" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="G" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's another version of the same layout using `RelativeLayout`.  I started with the nested `LinearLayouts` above, selected "**Refactor > Android > Change Layout...**", selected `RelativeLayout`, and then tweaked the resulting layout until I got things centered.

I used a couple of tricks to get it right.  I started by centering the middle button on the parent, then built out to the left and right.  On the top row, where there is an even number of buttons and space in the center, I used a centered, 0-width `TextView` to anchor the buttons.  That's a bit hacky, I guess, but it gets the job done. :-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Dummy"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Dummy"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Dummy"
    android:text="B" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Dummy"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="A" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Dummy"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Dummy"
    android:text="C" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Dummy"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="D" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Dummy"
    android:text="F" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button6"
    android:text="E" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:text="G" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Sparky, I guess nesting layouts might be the correct way to go about this type of design! I thought there might of been a neater method without the nesting, but I guess not! Thanks!

Comment: I amended my answer to include a version with no nesting.  I started with the nested version and used automated refactoring to help make the non-nested one.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping to see :) I'll have a tweak around with that to figure out how it all works. I think what I was after was "layout_alignBaseline". Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could also try it using the **weight**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="D" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="E" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="F" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="G" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"></LinearLayout>
    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
        android:id="@+id/v1"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/pos"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/neu"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/neg"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/neg"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l2"
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/l3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/pos"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/neu"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/neg"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l3"
        android:id="@+id/v3"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks AkashG. Same comment as to Sparky ;)

Comment: But there is a lot difference between what Sparky provided and what i provided to you.Implement the above code,you'll find exact what ur requirement is.thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using linear layout instead. in the first linear layout set the weightsum to 4 and the layout weight to 1 to make it equal divided and set each views gravity to center.
Do the same thing in send Linear Layout.